# Using Activation Context API in C++ component

Tags: c++, com, regfreecom, activation-context-api

I am a c# developer currently working on some legacy c++ com components. I am trying to add activation context api code to the com components in order to call other com components without registration.

I wrote a dummy c++ project to play with the activation context stuff and it worked no problem. However, when I added the same code into the legacy com component I can't even compile it: Error    1   error C2065: 'ACTCTX' : undeclared identifier

I didn't add any special headers to my dummy project but it worked fine so I'm not sure why this is happening. Hopefully, this will be trivial for a seasoned c++ developer ...

Answer (score 2):

Changed this in stdafx.h:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
```

to

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
```

and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to change WINVER and _WIN32_WINDOWS to the same value, and then change _WIN32_IE to 0x0600.